# ElasticSearch separate index per user

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I'm wondering if having thousands of different indexes is a bad idea?

I'm adding a search page to my web app based on ElasticSearch. The search page lets users search for other users on the site by filtering on a number of different indexed criteria (name, location, gender etc). This is fairly straight forward and will require just one index that contains a document every user of the site.

However, I want to also create a page where users can see a list of all of the other users they follow. I want this page to have the same filtering options that are available on the search page. I'm wondering if a good way to go about this would be to create a separate index for each user containing documents for each user they follow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can certainly create thousands of indices in elasticsearch, I don't really see the need for it in your use case. I think you can use one index. Simply create an additional [child type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/parent-field.html) `followers` for the main user record. Every time user `A` follows user `B`, create a child record of `B` with the following content: `{"followed_by" : "A"}`. To get the list of users that current user is following, you can simply add [Has Child Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-filter.html) to you query.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to Igor's answer that creating thousand of indexes on a tiny cluster (one or two nodes) can cause some drawbacks.
Each shard of an index is a full Lucene instance. That said, you will have many opened files (probably too many opened files) if you have a single node (or a small cluster - in term of nodes).

That's one of the major reasons why I would not define too many indices...

See also [File descriptors on installation guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html)

Comment: Excellent point! If David didn't convince you yet, I can also add that having a lot of indices will slow down cluster restarts and repeating user data will make modification and deletion of user records more complicated that it needs to be. In other words, you can have a lot of indices, but in your case it's, probably, a bad idea.